# Google Analytics/Tag Master - Tracking unique pageviews with events on a given page

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-tag-manager

I have set up GA & GTM to do the following:

1. Track when an outgoing link is clicked.
2. Track when an outgoing email address is clicked (mailto:)

Google Analytics records this as 2 separate events, for example
I go onto page 'Example Page 1' and click 2 outgoing links, and 1 outgoing email address.
GA summarizes for Example Page 1: 2 outgoing link clicks (1 unique event) and 1 outgoing email address click (1 unique event) - total 2 unique events.
In the above scenario I would like GA to consider my actions as a single event. In other words I want GA to record the number of unique pageviews with EITHER a outgoing link click or email address click.

The overall aim is to be able to say Example Page 1 had 5000 unique page views, with 2000 of these page views including someone clicking either an outbound link or an email address.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

My own opinion is that they should be kept as seperate events as they are both different types of actions.

What you could do is setup a single event goal, based on those two different event types.
Say for example the GA category for your outbound link event is Outbound Link & then the GA Category for your contact link event is Contact.
Create an Event goal configured as Category > Regular Expression > Outbound Link|Contact